# Aproximate calculation in decimals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, arithmetic, approximation, fractions

I am trying to refresh on precision of calculations.
If we have the decimal fractions:
$.234673$, $.322135$, $.114342$, $.563217$ each known to be correct to six figures why are each of the decimals may not be accurate by as much as $.0000005$?
How do we come up with this number?
If I recall if e.g. he have $32.71$ the $1$ represents 1 hundrenth instead of 1 unit but is still $1/3271$ of the total, right?
But using $3/234673$ for the first decimal, $5/322135$ for the second $2/114342$ for the third and $7/563217$ for the last I don't get $0.0000005$.
So how do we find the approximation?

Answer (score 2):

The thing to note is that numbers in the range $0.2346725-0.2346734\dot{9}$ all round to $0.235673$. The maximum error here is $0.0000005$. It is a similar argument for all of the other numbers.

In general, a number $a\times10^p$, with $a$ an integer (no decimal part), has maximum error $5\times10^{p-1}$.

**Edit in response to below comments**

The absolute and relative error ([defined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Definitions)) measure the error in two different ways.

Absolute error measured the difference between the actual and approximate value, taking no regard to the size of the numbers. 30 to approximate 31 and 1470 to approximate 1469 both have an absolute error of 1.

Relative error measures the percentage that the error is of the actal value. Using the same numbers as the above example, the relative error using 30 to approximate 31 is $1/31\approx0.03225$ and using 1470 to approximate 1469, the relative error is $1/1469\approx0006807$. So even though both of these approximations have an absolute error of $1$, they have very different relative errors.

Comment: But if the actual number was e.g. 3271 and the approximate number was 3270 I would be off by `1/3271=0.0003` I.e. `+/-` 3 in tenth thousand.So why doesn't this approach work in fractional decimals?

Comment: @Jim So $3270=327\times10^1$. We would expect an error less than $5\times10^0=5$, which is indeed the case (actual error is $1$). What I have measured is the *absolute error*. What you are measuring is the *relative error*, which is quite different.

Comment: How did you come up that the error would be less that `5*10^0`?Also what is the difference between absolute and relative error?

Comment: @Jim The answer by mau describes significant digits, so I won't add to it. I got that error by using my "formula" above, but also noting that any value in the range $3275-3274.\dot{9}$ will round to $3270$. The maximum that my error could be then is $5$.

Answer (score 1):

well, it depends on what you mean by correct "to six figures". Usually it is intended to six **significant** digits, so that the leading 0 is not counted among them; but since you are saying that this is not the case I'll change my answert.

The first number is greater than or equal to $0.23467$ and less than $0.23468$, so the maximum
possible error is $0.000007$.

Moreover, this error is **absolute**, that is, the difference between the actual value and the given one. $3/234673$ or $7/234673$ is a **relative** error, that is, the ratio between the error and the given value. In this case the difference is small, but if you have the number $2346734$ with six correct digits the result changes.

Comment: Six figures means six figures and not decimal places.So `0.` is also counted.Also I don't know what is absolute/relative error

Comment: ok, for me it was six **significant** figures and leading zero is not. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @Jim: No, it makes no sense to treat 0. as a significant figure. If you multiply or divide a number by 10, it should not change the number of significant figures (although it does change the number of decimal places). So 0.123 has the same number of significant figures as 1.23 and 0.0123.